# Xamarin Android: Hide Keyboard on Fragment

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I have two fragments on a viewpager. Since one fragment has EditTexts on it and the other has just graphics on it, I would like to hide the keyboard when I switch onto the graphic fragment.

Comment: Hi, I have edited my answer, please try it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implement `ViewPager.IOnPageChangeListener` in your `xxxxActivity`( which contains the `ViewPager`). And use [addOnPageChangeListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#addOnPageChangeListener(android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener))( [setOnPageChangeListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOnPageChangeListener(android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener)) was deprecated in API level 24.1.0.) to add listener on your `ViewPager`.

In the `OnPageSelected` method:

```
public void OnPageSelected(int position)
{

    if (position == 0)
    {
        // because the keyboard has been forced to hide in graphic fragment,
        // when you back to edittext fragment, you need force to show it.
        EditTextFragment.showKeyboard();
    }
    else if (position == 1)
    {
        //In your graphic fragment, hide the keyboard.
            var im = ((InputMethodManager)GetSystemService(Android.Content.Context.InputMethodService));

            if (CurrentFocus!= null)
            {
                im.HideSoftInputFromWindow(CurrentFocus.WindowToken, HideSoftInputFlags.None);
            }
    }
}
```

`EditTextFragment.showKeyboard();` method:

```
    if (editText.RequestFocus())
    {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)Activity.GetSystemService(Android.Content.Context.InputMethodService);
        imm.ShowSoftInput(editText,ShowFlags.Implicit );
    }
```

Comment: Do you mean something like: 
`viewPager.PageSelected += ViewPager_PageSelected;`
And then:
`private void ViewPager_PageSelected(object sender, 
     ViewPager.PageSelectedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Position == 0)
            {` and so on

Comment: Well i tried it, debuged it, but `((InputMethodManager)GetSystemService(Context.InputMethodService)).
                HideSoftInputFromInputMethod(CurrentFocus.WindowToken, HideSoftInputFlags.NotAlways);` doesn't seem to do anything. The keyboard stays where it is...

Comment: @DevNoteHQ, I have edited my answer about `else if (position == 1)`, try again.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a static method for this in a sort of Utils class inside your Xamarin.Android project. Might look kind of like this:

```
public static class Utils
{
    public static void HideKeyboard(Activity context)
    {
        var imm = (InputMethodManager)context.GetSystemService(Context.InputMethodService);
        int sdk = (int)Build.VERSION.SdkInt;

        if (sdk < 11)
        {
            imm.HideSoftInputFromWindow(context.Window.CurrentFocus.WindowToken, 0);
        }
        else
        {
           imm.HideSoftInputFromWindow(context.CurrentFocus.WindowToken, HideSoftInputFlags.NotAlways);
        }
    }
}
```

Take a look at [GetSystemService(java.lang.String)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSystemService(java.lang.String)) and the [InputMethodManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodManager.html) class.

Comment: Well it seams like multiple of those commands are not available in a FragmentActivity. And why should i add another class? What does that change?

Comment: @DevNoteHQ Are you sure you have imported the right using statements? Adding another static class like this means you only have to write it once and can use it in multiple activities, which might be handy in the future, as such: Utils.HideKeyboard(activity);

activity being your FragmentActivity that you pass.

Comment: Well i used the using statements that Visual Studio recommended... It's such a small piece of code, that i don't really want to bloat my small app with an additional class.

Comment: @DevNoteHQ The extra class isn't really obliged, just a recommendation.